# Blender and other 3D applications don't launch

Tags: linux, 3d, blender, amd-gpu, arch

Sys specs; Arch, Ryzen 5 5600x, Radeon 570X, 16GB ram.

I reinstalled my arch install a month ago and tried to open blender with this message:

```
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

the contents of that file is:

```
# Blender 4.0.1, Commit date: 2023-11-16 16:40, Hash d0dd92834a08

# backtrace
blender(+0xfd0683) [0x5599af4d6683]
blender(+0x8ba21e) [0x5599aedc021e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3e710) [0x7fe85316f710]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-15.so(+0x17a7a0f) [0x7fe847da7a0f]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-15.so(+0x17a7b98) [0x7fe847da7b98]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm14FoldingSetBase19FindNodeOrInsertPosERKNS_16FoldingSetNodeIDERPvRKNS0_14FoldingSetInfoE+0xb6) [0x7fe85e9278e6]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm12SelectionDAG11getRegisterEjNS_3EVTE+0xbe) [0x7fe85f4cbd3e]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(+0x3a0e7ce) [0x7fe86160e7ce]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel14LowerArgumentsERKNS_8FunctionE+0xef3) [0x7fe85f48f453]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel20SelectAllBasicBlocksERKNS_8FunctionE+0x22dc) [0x7fe85f50632c]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(+0x19079b6) [0x7fe85f5079b6]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(+0x12ea945) [0x7fe85eeea945]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm13FPPassManager13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE+0x459) [0x7fe85ebab989]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(+0x282aefa) [0x7fe86042aefa]
/usr/lib/libLLVM-16.so(_ZN4llvm6legacy15PassManagerImpl3runERNS_6ModuleE+0x3ec) [0x7fe85ebac6ac]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x82f380) [0x7fe808e2f380]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x830009) [0x7fe808e30009]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x84fffc) [0x7fe808e4fffc]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x85c2cf) [0x7fe808e5c2cf]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x867c4d) [0x7fe808e67c4d]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xc8bbd9) [0x7fe80928bbd9]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xca4926) [0x7fe8092a4926]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xbad593) [0x7fe8091ad593]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xbc7239) [0x7fe8091c7239]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x8a92dc) [0x7fe808ea92dc]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x8b6fe2) [0x7fe808eb6fe2]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x609487) [0x7fe808c09487]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x5e8219) [0x7fe808be8219]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x147f72a) [0x7fe809a7f72a]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x60b018) [0x7fe808c0b018]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0x18753f) [0x7fe80878753f]
/usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so(+0xbe454) [0x7fe8086be454]
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x5397f) [0x7fe8316d397f]
/usr/lib/libGLX_mesa.so.0(+0x3f58b) [0x7fe8316bf58b]
blender(+0x294a356) [0x5599b0e50356]
blender(+0x2949928) [0x5599b0e4f928]
blender(+0x293f759) [0x5599b0e45759]
blender(+0x294968b) [0x5599b0e4f68b]
blender(+0x2946028) [0x5599b0e4c028]
blender(+0x293bca4) [0x5599b0e41ca4]
blender(+0x10167d2) [0x5599af51c7d2]
blender(+0x1016a1d) [0x5599af51ca1d]
blender(+0xfe0454) [0x5599af4e6454]
blender(+0xff62de) [0x5599af4fc2de]
blender(+0xffb9f4) [0x5599af5019f4]
blender(+0x88d681) [0x5599aed93681]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x27cd0) [0x7fe853158cd0]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x8a) [0x7fe853158d8a]
blender(+0x8b5e05) [0x5599aedbbe05]

# Python backtrace
```

I reinstalled the Radeon drivers with no change.

I also tried to open a 3D game which also crashed.

I am at a loss.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be programming related and might be better suited for sites like https://superuser.com/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Unfortunately I'm not super experienced with Arch. The one thing I'd try to rule out is relataed to libc: double checking if there were no major arch kernel upgrades that might have resulted in newer versions of libc installed on your system while blender and other apps use an older / mismatching libc version? (Try reinstalling blender for example. The other thing to rule out is a radeon gpu driver issue: try compiling an opengl sample)

Comment: Thanks George I will try superuser form, blender form told me to try this one.